# Failed extracting a value from an object using enum as key and casting to enum type (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I am getting loads of errors as I am trying to extract an object by its key which is an enum type. And cast it as that enum type.

After the type is extracted, I pass it through to a function that will further proceed to process the data based on that type.

```
export enum TestElement {
  Type = 'T',
  Serial = 'S',
}

const data = '{"TEST1":{"T":"XX2","S":8374373}}';

const parsed: object = JSON.parse(data);

// Get the first element
const extracted: object = Object.values(parsed)[0];

// Get the type
const type: TestElement = extracted[TestElement.Type];

handler(type, extracted)();
```

For `const type: TestElement = extracted[TestElement.Type]` I get the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'TestElement.Type' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property '[TestElement.Type]' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(7053)
```

---

```
const handler = (
  type: TestElement,
  data: object,
): (() => void) =>
  processTypes[type]
    ? () => processTypes[type](data[type]())
    : () => {
        throw new Error(
          'Type not supported or unknown',
        );
      };
```

Then for `processTypes[type](data[type]())` I get the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'TestElement' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property '[TestElement.Type]' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(7053)
```

---

```
const processTypes: {
  [key: string]: (data: {[key in TestElement]: string}) => void;
} = {
  XX1: data => {
    console.log({data});
  },
  XX2: data => {
    console.log({data});
  },
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there even the correct way to go about it?